# JS, jQuery: How do you make a chained jQuery animation NOT wait until the previous animation is done?

Tags: animation, jquery, queue, jquery-animate

As you may know, if you chain jQuery animations together using the "complete" parameter, each animation happens in succession only after the previous is complete.

I have a chain, like this:

```
$('#foobar').load(url, function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(time, function(){
        $(this).scrollTop(position, time, function() {
            $(this).css({'color':'#58e'})
        });
    });
});
```

This chain will execute something like this: first load content, then fade in, then scroll to the top, then finally change the css color.

What I want is this: first load the content, then fade in and scroll to the top at the same time, then finally change the color after `fadeIn` and `scrollTop` are both done.

Let's say the `scrollTop` animation takes twice as long than the `fadeIn` animation. What simple piece of code would I add to my code so that the `scrollTop` callback in `fadeIn` DOESN'T wait for the `fadeIn` animation to complete. The `css()` animation will wait for the `scrollTop` animation to complete, like normal.

So the only change (whatever it might be) would affect the callback within `fadeIn` where `scrollTop` is called. I'm guessing it might have to do with manipulating the queue?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Here's the solution as hinted by Andrew:

First, my original code which loads each custom function in order:

```
show_loader(0, function() {
    close_box($target_close, '/', '#' + $target_close.attr('id') + ' .post_wrap', function() {
        open_box($target_open, event.value, '.wide-col', function() {
            hide_loader(function() {
                scroll_to_content($target_open);
            });
            $target_close = $target_open;
        });
    });
});
```

Now I want close_box and open_box to execute asynchronously (at the same time), so I changed it to this:

```
show_loader(0, function() {
    close_box($target_close, '/', '#' + $target_close.attr('id') + ' .post_wrap');
    open_box($target_open, event.value, '.wide-col', function() {
        hide_loader(function() {
            scroll_to_content($target_open);
        });
        $target_close = $target_open;
    });
});
```

Now close_box and open_box animations happen at the "same time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code that animates `scrollTop` outside of the callback to the `fadeIn` function:

```
$('#foobar').load(url, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(time);            
    $(this).scrollTop(position, time, function() {
        $(this).css({'color':'#58e'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Won't that just naturally queue up the "scrollTop" to run after the "fadeIn" anyway?

Comment: I understand that. The problem is though i'm actually chaining multiple custom functions that contain multiple animations within. I'm passing the callback to the animation that takes longest within each function. Can i use "next()" to bypass the wait time somehow?

Comment: @Pointy: `scrollTop` will run after `fadeIn` but it will not wait for `fadeIn` to complete before beginning.

Comment: @andrew The situation i'm in limits me from doing that particular solution though. Any way to use next() somehow?